# Admin user to not able to login to other database on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

mongo user can able to login on admin database.But can't able to login other databases.

I have given following privileges to the user.

Privileges command :

```
db.createUser( { user: "root", pwd: "password", roles: [ "readWriteAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin" ]} )
```

While accessing to other DB form Mongo Shell I got below error

Command line :

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe database-name -u root -p

2014-12-01T12:00:05.806+0000 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

So How can I give access to the DB with the same user?Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to authenticate to the database where the user exists. The easiest way to do this with the shell is to use `--authenticationDatabase`

```
mongo.exe database-name -u root -p ***** --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working fine from mongo shell.And I can view the database from robo mongo client but I can't able to see a collections with root user.